# Как решить задачу, и возможно ли решить ее на Python 3?

Tags: python, математика

Пусть x,y,z - натуральные числа. Известно, что произведение xyz=14745600. На какую максимальную степень двойки может делиться x^2+y^2+z^2 ?

Comment: Можно тупо перебором. Раскладываете 14745600 на простые множители, находите все комбинации, которыми из этих простых множителей можно получить три натуральных числа, для каждой тройки вычисляете сумму квадратов, определяете сколько раз оно делится на 2, выбираете максимальное значение.

Answer (score 1):

Разложим 14745600 на простые множители, получим 2^16*3^2*5^2

Уже понятно, что наибольшую степень 2 мы получим, если каждое - x,y,z - сделаем кратным по 2^5. x=2^5*k, y=2^5*l, z=2^5*m. Получаем x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2^10*(k^2+l^2+m^2)

Где klm = 2*9*25=450. Теперь можно и небольшим перебором проверить все k^2+l^2+m^2 и посмотреть, на какую степень 2 они делятся.

Это уже совсем просто - типа

```
max2 = 0
for k in range(1,22):
    if 450%k != 0: continue
    for l in range(k+1,450//k+1):
        if 450//k%l != 0: continue

        m = 450//k//l
        m = m*m+k*k+l*l
        cnt = 0
        while(m%2 == 0):
            cnt = cnt + 1
            m = m//2
        if max2 < cnt: max2=cnt

print(max2)
```

Наверняка можно и умнее :), но уже этот перебор показывает, что максимум, на что делится k^2+l^2+m^2 - это на 2 в первой степени. А потому - максимальная степень - 2^11...

Но это же можно показать и руками - понятно, что в одно из чисел входит 2, два остальных - нечетны. Т.е. числа имеют вид k = 2*(2a+1), l = 2b+1, m = 2c+1. Возводя в квадраты и суммируя, находим

4*(4a^2+4a+1)+(4b^2+4b+1)+4c^2+4c+1 = 4*(....)+2 - т.е. делиться на 4 это число не может, только на 2, а значит - вот еще одна степень 2.

Итог - 10+1 = 11, и никакого Питона :)